# How debug process that not started with ida?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging

I am trying to debug two different exe files,in windows.

The first exe launches the second, and the second exe doesn't work well unless the first starts it.

I want to be able to debug the second exe.

I want to debug the begging of the exe, so attaching isn't an option.

Does IDA have a way to debug a process that's launched by another?

Comment: The references to "exe" makes me think that this is about windows, and therefore not a dup

Comment: @Avery3R Although linked question seems to revolve around ELF files specifically, I believe the answer applies just the same regardless of OS.

Comment: @Megabeets that not help, event I breakpoint in `fork` or`execve` I can't debug the new process in the beginning

Answer (score 3):

In a similar way, windows services must also be started by a special process. Microsoft [has documentation on how to debug these kinds of processes.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824344/how-to-debug-windows-services)

The applicable section is "Configure a service to start with the WinDbg debugger attached"

1. Locate the following registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
2. Create a new subkey with the name of the executable
3. Within that subkey create a new string value named `Debugger`
4. Set that value to the path to your debugger. See [IDA's documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) for the needed command line flags.